# Clip shapefile and keep the outer part of it

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, clip, erase

I have to two polygon layers, the red layer is the the bottom layer.

[image]

The second layer covers most of the bottom layer

[image]

I would like to know if there is a tool that will create a polygon layer of just the red parts showing in the second photo.

The parts of image one that are visible in image two?

Comment: Can you give details?What values do you have to your second image for each color??

Comment: pink = road, blue = path

Comment: Don't you have values(eg road=10)? Perhaps if your files are rasters you can use raster calculator. With an expression you can choose only the red.(eg blue=1, red=2,pink=3. to raster calculator the x_output would be something like: "file_2==2".) If is that all you want to do.

Comment: they are both polygon layers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have an Advanced license, you can use [Erase](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Erase/00080000000m000000/). If you don't, [Union](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Union/00080000000s000000/) is an option: run the tool then delete resulting features with attributes from both inputs and with attributes from the second layer only.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using QGIS you can use the toll Difference that will give you the difference between the two shapes.